# How can I find a free or cheap redistributable font supporting runic characters?

Tags: fonts, distribution

I've been looking around for a font to include in my game which supports rune characters, specifically [this Unicode block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/runic/index.htm).

All the sites I go to don't demonstrate what Unicode characters that font contains, so I cannot gauge their usefulness for me.

I've been using the *Segoe UI Symbol* font, but it is only available on Win 7 & 8, and as far as I can tell, costs far too much to redistribute as part of a game.

Anyone know where I can go to find a font with my requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fileformat.info page you linked to](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/runic/index.htm) contains a link [“Fonts that support this block”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/runic/fontsupport.htm). The ones listed there with 100% support are—

- [Everson Mono](http://evertype.com/emono/) (*cost*: €25; *license*: [Everson Mono Shareware License](http://evertype.com/emono/licence.html)), and
- [GNU Unifont](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/unifont/) (*cost*: free; *license*: [GNU GPL, with virality-exemption for embedding](http://unifoundry.com/LICENSE.txt))

Comment: The latter begs the question if a game fulfills the definition of "document" or if including it in a game forces the whole game to be open-sourced under GNU GPL. I [forwarded this question to Open Source Stackexchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/does-using-gnu-unifont-for-a-game-make-the-game-gpl).

Comment: Regarding the first, when you want to use it in a game, it might cost far more than €25. The license conditions read: *"If your company is interested in licensing Everson Mono for bundling with your software, please get in touch with me directly."*

Comment: The "Fonts that support this block" is the most useful part of this. I may be going with another font in that list called _Cardo_ which has 90% support (and I believe supports all the characters I need). It also specifically mentions that one can sell "games and entertainment software" using the font, so I'm quite happy with this option.

Thanks for the help!